# ANTLR wildcard operator not consuming expected input

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, antlr3

I'm writing an antlr grammar that reads in yacc specification file. Yacc spec files are of the form

```
declarations 
%%
rules 
%%
programs
```

However, I'm only interested in the declarations and rules sections of the yacc spec file. I have defined rules which match the declarations and rules well but I was trying to match everything that comes after the second '%%' using a wildcard operator (.*?). This fails. Here's the
[Link to my anltr grammar for yacc grammars](https://gist.github.com/miraselimo/7bf22c8a4364d6316e1ada88d2fb2b25)

How can I match whatever that comes after the second '%%'.

I have also tried matching anything but the EOF using

```
<some_rule> : ~(EOF)* ;
```

[Here's an example of the file that fails](https://gist.github.com/miraselimo/7e0e6cabaa52b397b60bd2db63bdf86e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is create a separate lexer grammar so that you can use [lexical modes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes).

That way, you start in the default declaration mode and when you encounter `%%` for the first time, you push into the `RULE_MODE`. When you encounter another `%%`, you push into the `SUBROUTINE_MODE`. In this last mode, you simply `skip` all characters you encounter.

A quick demo:

```
// File: YaccLexer.g4
lexer grammar YaccLexer;

DECLARATION_TOKEN
 : [a-zA-Z]+
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
 ;

DECLARATION_END
 : '%%' -> skip, pushMode(RULE_MODE)
 ;

mode RULE_MODE;

  RULE_TOKEN
   : [a-zA-Z]+
   ;

  SPACES_RULE_TOKEN
   : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
   ;

  RULE_END
   : '%%' -> skip, pushMode(SUBROUTINE_MODE)
   ;

mode SUBROUTINE_MODE;

  ANY
   : . -> skip
   ;
```

If you generate a lexer from the grammar above, and tokenise the input:

```
foo
bar

%%

baz

%%

ignore
me
```

the following tokens would be created:

```
DECLARATION_TOKEN         'foo'
DECLARATION_TOKEN         'bar'
RULE_TOKEN                'baz'
```

You can use your `YaccLexer` in your parser grammar like this:

```
// File: YaccParser.g4
parser grammar YaccParser;

options {
  tokenVocab= YaccLexer;
}

// your parser rules here
```